# Calculating a value and rounding to nearest whole number

Tags: c#, math, variables, double, rounding

I'm trying to calculate a number below. I keep getting 0 when it should be something like `83.12454`.

I believe i want a `Double` variable type. What am I doing wrong below? Once I get the value I need to trim the decimal.

```
Ratings GetNoVotes = new Ratings();
int DATotalYesVotes = GetNoVotes.GetTotalNOVotes(1, yesPictureId); //80
int DaTNoVotes = GetNoVotes.GetTotalNOVotes(2, yesPictureId);      //15
int DaTotalVotes = DATotalYesVotes + DaTNoVotes;                   //95

double Percentage = (DATotalYesVotes / DaTotalVotes)*100;          //84.2105
// Math.Round(Percentage);
TotalyesVotes.Text = Percentage.ToString();
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out your intermediate values? i.e. DATotalYesVotes etc

Comment: The usual trick involves `Math.Floor(x + .5)` IIRC

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that DATotalYesVotes is an integer less than DaTotalVotes.  Because / means integer division, it rounds down before multiplying by 100.  Here are two approaches:

(1) Multiply by 100 first (still some roundoff error - but not much)

```
double Percentage = (DATotalYesVotes * 100 / DaTotalVotes);
```

(2) Cast to doubles first

```
double Percentage = ((double)DATotalYesVotes / (double)DATotalVotes)*100;
```

Comment: Thanks I kinda thought id have to do something like that. It worked perfectly. Apreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert DATotalYesVotes and DaTotalVotes to double before dividing them:

```
double Percentage = ((double)DATotalYesVotes / (double)DaTotalVotes)*100.0;
```

Other wise the division of 2 ints will result in a 3rd (and truncated) int.

Answer (score 1):

The integer division yields an integer result of zero, then you multiply it by 100. Try casting to double for one of the numbers.

```
double Percentage = ((double)DATotalYesVotes / DaTotalVotes)*100;
```